# In this p5.js code I am not getting background color even when mouse is pressed

Tags: p5.js, generative-art

Plss tell me whats the error in this code here i am not getting background colour even when mouse is pressed , i am supposed to get alternatively black and green when mouse is pressed
function mousePressed() is not executing

```js
var on = false;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400);
}

function draw() {
  if (on) {
    if (mouseIsPressed) {
      background(0, 255, 0);
    } else {
      background(0);
    }
  }

  background(0);
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(4);
  noFill();

  if (mouseX > 250 && mouseX < 350 && mouseY > 150 && mouseY < 250) {
    fill(255, 0, 200);
  }

  rectMode(CENTER);
  rect(300, 200, 100, 100);

  function mousePressed() {
    if (mouseX > 250 && mouseX < 350 && mouseY > 150 && mouseY < 250) {
      on = !on;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There were two issues with your code:

1. The `mousePressed()` event handler function was declared inside the draw function instead of globally.
2. You were always calling `background(0)` **after** the if block that would sometimes call `background(0, 255, 0)` which meant that the background would always be black regardless of what happened in the initial if block.

```js
var on = false;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400);
}

function draw() {
  if (on) {
    if (mouseIsPressed) {
      background(0, 255, 0);
    } else {
      background(0);
    }
  } else {
    background(0);
  }

  // This would re-draw the background black regardless of what happened above
  // background(0);
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(4);
  noFill();

  if (mouseX > 250 && mouseX < 350 && mouseY > 150 && mouseY < 250) {
    fill(255, 0, 200);
  }

  rectMode(CENTER);
  rect(300, 200, 100, 100);
}

// This used to be declared inside the draw() function. Event handlers in p5.js need to be declared globally
function mousePressed() {
  if (mouseX > 250 && mouseX < 350 && mouseY > 150 && mouseY < 250) {
    on = !on;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```